# libicucore.A.dylib,libz.1.2.5.dylib,libstdc++.dylib missing from libraries in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

In my xcode 4.3 the library files libz.1.2.5.dylib,libstdc++.dylib,libicucore.A.dylib etc are missing .When I click on link binary with libraries,these files are not getting listed.What should I do if it got deleted by someone ? Plese suggest some solutions?

Comment: you can try reinstall Xcode 4.3 from the App store

Comment: That is the only way to recover it?Or can I download these files separately?